How to resize the time-frequency spectrum of 1D signal so that image classification model can be used?
In case of 1D signal generally they tend to be around 1000s of sample points for each trial especially for biomedical signal. The time-frequency spectrum then can have shape like [256,1000] or [50,1000] etc.
However most popular image classification CNN models tend to take input in the shape of [224,224] etc.
In that case what is the proper procedure of resizing the time-frequency spectrum?
